# Importing .reg file returns success-message but does not import values

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, windows-registry, regedit

I have made a simple reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"JPEGImportQuality"=DWORD:0x64
```

When I open PowerShell and use `reg import test.reg` I get the message "The process was finished successfully".
When I simply double-click the file in Explorer, or open regedit and click on File->import, I get similar messages.

When I then look at the key in regedit, I don't see the value.

[image: Image. A screenshot of Windows registry entries. The registry entry from the registry file given earlier is not shown]

Both PowerShell and regedit are opened as administrator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.reg` file has the incorrect syntax `0x64`, which for some reason
`regedit` ignores without giving an error.

Use this file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"JPEGImportQuality"=dword:00000064
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In addition though, you also have to write "dword" in lower case.